# Os.system doesn't push message in cron alert to cronitor?

Tags: python, cron, os.system

I am running a python script using a cron job. When the script runs, it either alerts that it completed or failed. It is supposed to send a message to cronitor along with the completion ping. An example of the link is below:

```
 https://cronitor.link/p/id/key?state=complete&msg='Success'
```

When I just put the link into the search bar and hit Enter, the message shows up in cronitor. However, when I try to get the message to print when running the link through the script it doesn't work. Cronitor gets the ping that it completed successfully but no message shows up:

```
 cron_alert = "/usr/local/bin/curl --silent https://cronitor.link/p/id/key?state=complete&msg='Success'"
 os.system(cron_alert)
```

I tried removing '--silent' but that didn't make a difference. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command contains an unescaped `&`, which the shell used by `os.system` parses as a command terminator that runs `curl` the the background. You need to escape it, e.g.

```
 cron_alert = \
   "/usr/local/bin/curl --silent \"https://cronitor.link/p/id/key?state=complete&msg='Success'\""
```

but even better would be to stop using `os.system` and use `subprocess.run` instead.

```
import subprocess


subprocess.run(["/usr/local/bin/curl",
                "--silent",
                "https://cronitor.link/p/id/key?state=complete&msg='Success'"])
```

which bypasses the shell altogether.

Best, use a library like `requests` to send the request from Python, rather than forking a new process.

```
import requests

requests.get("https://cronitor.link/p/id/key",
              params={'state': 'complete', 'msg': "'Success'"})
```

(In all cases, does the API really require single quotes around `Success`?)

Comment: Thanks that worked! I used the requests solution, but using payload didn't work. I had to change that to 'params' and then it went through. And to your questions about the quotes, it does not require it I was testing it with and without to see if that would work.

Comment: Sorry, I got the names reversed from the [example](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) (`params=payload`, not `payload=params`). (You can tell how often I use `requests` myself...)